# Zend Framework class filenames in windows vs. linux

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

Background: We often work on web applications which are developed in PHP (Zend Framework) and hosted on a linux server. The programming team may consist of individuals that may use either Linux or Windows for their local development platform.

Because Zend model names are mapped into filenames, case matters.
A programmer may write $this->something, where "something" is a model that has a filename on the linux server of "Something.php".

His code will work fine on his Windows development PC, because "something" will correctly map to "Something.php" on windows. But when uploaded to the linux server, the code will break because the filename is case-sensitive on Linux. He should have written the code as "$this->Something".

So finally my question, is there a Zend Framework configuration that will generate an error even in Windows, if the system detects that the case of the model name in code doesn't match the case of the actual filename in the filesystem?

Comment: Retagged. Zend != Zend Framework.

Comment: The bottom line is, no there isn't, stick to naming conventions!

Comment: @markus - we do use the naming conventions. The issue arises when a programmer makes a typo (types lowercase instead of uppercase), and it silently still works on Windows, then fails on Linux. It would be nice to detect this.

Comment: @royappa: true, our team works on windows and we don't have trouble with that. If you use an IDE with Zend Framework support, you don't actually get much chance to make typo... I hope you have a staging environment which is the same as live. if you can detect the rare cases there, isn't it enough?

Comment: @markus: it happens rarely (as rarely as any other kind of typo). Yes we have a staging environment where this was picked up and everything is tested there first before putting on live. I was just hoping for a simple flag or option to avoid the problem entirely just like there are many flags for various types of error checking. Thanks for the good suggestions though.

Answer (score 2):

> So finally my question, is there a
>   Zend Framework configuration that will
>   generate an error even in Windows, if
>   the system detects that the case of
>   the model name in code doesn't match
>   the case of the actual filename in the
>   filesystem?

Not that I'm aware of, but it would be pretty easy to add some checks in to a copy of ZF on a development server / workstation.  ZF uses spl_autoload_register to load classes, and all the logic to convert class names to filesystem locations lives in the Loader namespace.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that the framework itself may have a setting for this, but if not, this is a nice suggestion as to where this could be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

## ZF Naming Conventions

Zend Framework coding convention state that you should use uppercase names. 
Some of the conventions are as important to follow as the API docs themself.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

> If a class name is comprised of more
>   than one word, the first letter of
>   each new word must be capitalized.
>   Successive capitalized letters are not
>   allowed, e.g. a class "Zend_PDF" is
>   not allowed while "Zend_Pdf" is
>   acceptable.

and

> Class names may only contain
>   alphanumeric characters. Numbers are
>   permitted in class names but are
>   discouraged in most cases. Underscores
>   are only permitted in place of the
>   path separator; the filename
>   "Zend/Db/Table.php" must map to the
>   class name "Zend_Db_Table".

As a note, your example provided was wrong.
But in any event, keep your model names all uppercase, and the path to the models also uppercase inline with the ZF naming conventions.

Comment: We do understand the conventions and follow them, when defining classes and creating files. The question (if unclear) was about how to detect errors, on Windows, when the class is INVOKED with a typo (lower case instead of uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.php) might help you.

Never tried it, but from what I understand, you can define rules to validate your code, thus define rules based on the filename case for your problem.

There is a already defined `Zend` ruleset from what I read, maybe it already has this kind of rule enclosed (or maybe the `PEAR` ruleset also).